# How do I go line by line in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, scheduling

I am looking to be able to loop through line by line of my dataframe, checking certain criteria, (if a staff member is available at a certain time etc.) and adding them to a list if they are available. To do this I plan on looping through each row of my dataframe until it's gone through them all. Having some trouble currently, any help is appreciated. In the example, I just want it to simply count the rows, just so I know the looping through actually works. [This](https://lhamu.medium.com/building-a-custom-staff-scheduling-model-a-beginners-journey-using-simple-python-c568c9965940) is what I am trying to replicate in the end. If anyone has knows how they can help achieve the end goal I will appreciate that greatly.

ps. I am not too experienced so sorry if this is a silly question, don't be too harsh.

```
def staffEarlyShift(staff):
    x = 1
    staff_shift = []
    for i in range(len(staff)):
        print (x)
        x = x + 1

staffEarlyShift(staff_df)
```

**dataframe**

```
    staffID                   days_can_work time_can_work     role
0         1  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
1         2  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
2         3  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
3         4  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
4         5  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
5         6  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)     chef
6         7  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
7         8  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
8         9  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)     chef
9        10  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
10       11  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
11       12  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
12       13  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
13       14  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)     chef
14       15  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)     chef
15       16  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)     chef
16       17  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
17       18  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
18       19  [mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat,sun]         (9,7)  waitron
```

Comment: What information did you find when you searched for `pandas iterate through dataframe rows` or something similar? Also, what does your code have to do with anything? It simply prints out numbers in a loop...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/5327068) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of output you want, but you can use `if` statement in a loops and use `.iloc` for take dataframes by row like this:

```
staff_available = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if len(df['DayWork'].iloc[i]) == 7: # Condition Is Can Work Everyday
        staff_available.append(df.iloc[i].tolist())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(staff_available,columns = ['StaffID','DayWork','TimeWork','Role'])
```

And result like this:
[image]

You can change `if` statement by what kind of output you want (for example use time work)